# Change sync rate between SP and Outlook calendars

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, outlook, sharepoint-calendar, synchronisation

So I can connect my SP calendar to Outlook, but it takes forever to update the other when I add an event either in SP or in Outlook. I could manually update in outlook to get and push changes immediately, but that isn't helpful if someone else adds an event. How can I make it push and pull new events immediately? Or even five minutes rather than 30?

Comment: how do you sync the calendar,are you using Calendar Overlay?

Comment: I have a calendar in SP and just click the "Connect to Outlook" button in the Ribbon under the Calendar tab.